# Eager loading includes endless self-join tables without include tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, eager-loading, self-join

when i try to select some items, items are coming with their includes despite i did not include their object to linq

```
public List<Institution> GetListWithCities(Expression<Func<Institution,bool>> filter = null)
{

   using (var context = new DbContext())
   {
    return filter == null 
           ? context.Set<Institution>()
                    .Include(x => x.City)
                    .ToList() 
           : context.Set<Institution>()
                    .Include(x => x.City)
                    .Where(filter)
                    .ToList();
  }
}

[Table("Institution")]
 public class Institution{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public int CITY_ID;
    public int RESPONSIBLE_INSTUTION_ID;
    public virtual City City{ get; set; }
    public virtual Institution ResponsibleInstution{ get; set; }
}
```

I expect a result include with city of instution but my method returns city and responsible instution. And it continues recursively.

Comment: Have you added this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; in your context? Have you checked whether SQL Server Profiler generates query including Institution during data loading?

Comment: yes its added, i didnt share whole class to dont be confused. And i havent check sql provider stil.

Answer (score 1):

People tend to use `Include` instead of `Select` while they don't plan to use the functionality that `Include` gives, but still wasting the processing power that `Include` uses.

> In entity framework always use Select to fetch some data. Only user Include if you plan to update the included items.

One of the slower parts of a database query is the transport from the fetched data from the database management system to your local process. Hence it is wise to Select only those properties that you really plan to use.

Apparently your `Institution` is in exactly one `City`, namely the `City` that the foreign key (`CityId`?) is referring to. If `Institution` [10] is located in `City` [15], then `Institution.CityId` will have a value 15, equal to `City.Id`. So you are transferring this value twice.

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    IQueryable<Institution> filteredInstitutions = (filter == null) ?
        dbContext.Institutions :
        dbContext.Institutions.Where(filter);
    return filteredInstitutions.Select(institution => new Institution
    {
        // Select only the Institution properties that you actually plan to use:
        Id = institution.Id,
        Name = institution.Name,

        City = new City
        {
            Id = institution.City.Id,
            Name = institution.City.Name,
            ...
        }

        // not needed: you already know the value:
        // CityId = institution.City.Id,
});
```

**Possible improvement**
Apparently you chose to add a layer between entity framework and the users of your functions: although they use your functions, they don't really have to know that you use entity framework to access the database. This gives your the freedom to use SQL instead of entity framework. Hell, it even gives you the freedom to get rid of your database and use an XML file instead of a DBMS: your users won't know the difference: nice if you want to write unit tests.

Although you chose to separate the method you use to persist the data, you chose to expose your database layout, inclusive foreign keys to the outside world. This makes it more difficult to change your database in future: your users have to change as well.

Consider writing repository classes for Institution and City that only expose those properties that the users of your persistency really need. If people only query "some properties of institutions with some properties of the City in which they are located", or the other way round "Several properties of Cities with several properties of the Institutions located in these Cities", then they won't need the foreign keys.

The intermediate repository classes give you more freedom to change your database. Apart from that, it will give you the freedom to hide certain properties for certain users.

For instance: suppose you add the possibility to delete an institution, but you don't want to immediately delete all information about this institution, for instance because this allows you to restore if someone accidently deletes the institution, you might add a nullable property `ObsoleteDate`

Moest people that query institutions, don't want the obsolete institutions. If you had an intermediate repository institution class, where you omitted the `ObsoleteDate`, and all queries removed all `Institutions` that have a non-zero `ObsoleteData`, then for your users it would be as if an obsolete institution would have been deleted from the database.

Only one user will need access to the `ObsoleteDate`: a cleaner task, that every now and then deleted all `Institutions` that are obsolete for a considerable time.

A third improvement for an intermediate repository class would be that you can give different users access to the same data, with different interfaces: some users can only query information about institutions, some are also allowed to change some data, while others are allowed to change other data. If you give them an interface, they can break this by casting them back to the original Institution.

With separate repository classes, you will have the possibility to give each of these users their own data, and nothing more than this data.

The disadvantage of a repository pattern is that you have to think about different users, and create different query functions. The advantages is that a repository is easier to change and easier to test, and thus easier to keep everything bug free after future changes.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but it is a big workload to change entire infrastructure of project for now, I have to use include instead of select.